# A method for for Flash's SharedObjects similar to send(), but local?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, shared-objects

I'm accessing the same SharedObject from two different programs at the same time on the same computer (i.e. locally, not remotely), and I wanted to know in one program if the other program had changed the SharedObject (besides just refreshing it). I had thought that the send() method or sync event would work, but those only work on remotely accessed SharedObjects. Is there something similar I could use?

Comment: no you'll have to check and compare data on a regular basis that's all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have two swfs running on the same machine, LocalConnection will let one swf call functions in another swf.

Comment: Thanks for replying, I looked it up and that seems like exactly what I'm looking for! There's only one problem, I tried using it and I get the error "Error #2044: Unhandled SecurityErrorEvent:. text=Error #2047: Security sandbox violation: LocalConnection.send:" followed by "blah.swf cannot access blah2.swf", even though I used conn.allowDomain("localhost");

Comment: To fix this (temporarily at least), I added conn.allowDomain("*") and conn.client = this. Now no errors are popping up, but the method I called still isn't doing anything.

Comment: Also, I set up a StatusEvent listener on my sender, and it's giving me an error, but the code is null.

Comment: Hey! Post your code in new question so people can see you have a LocalConnection code question.  I don't have time now.

Comment: I did, but no one has even viewed it =\ - Thanks for your help, though!